# How to generete multiple DatagridviewColumns and populate them by different data?

Tags: c#

I am binding datagridview using datatable.
The problem is when i want to bind.

Instead of getting combobox in my datagridview I'am getting

> "DataGridViewComboBoxColumn { Name=Przedmioty, Index=-1 }"

This problem is caused because I haven't added this control to datagridview?
Datagridview cannot infer this from DataTable?
How to make this work with combobox filled with different data for every teacher, because when I add this combobox to datagridview all teachers will share the same instance of control with the same data.

```
 var result = (from T in Teachers
                              select
                              new
                              {
                                  TeachersName = T.Name,
                                  LecturesAssigned = T.Lectures.ToList(),

                             }).ToList();

 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Lectures", typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxColumn));
                DataGridViewComboBoxColumn lectures = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                lectures.DataPropertyName = "Lectures";
                lectures.Name = "Lectures";

            for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
            {
                foreach(Lecture l in result[i].LecturesAssigned)
                {
                    lectures.Items.Add(l.LectureName);
                }

                dt.Rows.Add(result[i].TeacherName, lectures);
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a combobox column in a datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692677/how-to-create-a-combobox-column-in-a-datatable)

Comment: No, add the column to the `Columns` collection. Don't create one column object and add the same column object to each row as data. The column itself isn't the data in that column.

Comment: It is better to open another form for editing DGV.  Then you can put real combo boxes on the editing form.